# Google Go: Why does the http server package not serve more than 5 simultaneous requests?

Tags: windows, http, go, httpserver

I'm trying to code a small http server for later extension in Google's Go language. I am using Go on Windows (MinGw compiled version).

This is quite easy in this language since it already has the necessary package:

```
package main

import (
    "http"
    "io"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)  


func FileTest(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    w.Header().Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=image.jpg")
    inName := "d:\\googlego\\somepic.jpg";
    inFile, inErr := os.OpenFile(inName, os.O_RDONLY, 0666);
    if inErr == nil {
        inBufLen := 16;
        inBuf := make([]byte, inBufLen);

        _, inErr := inFile.Read(inBuf);
        for inErr == nil {
            w.Write(inBuf)
            _, inErr = inFile.Read(inBuf);
        } 
    }
    inErr = inFile.Close(); 

}

func MainPage(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hi, download here: <a href=\"/FileTest\">HERE</a>")

}


func main() {
    fmt.Print("Port: ")
    var hi int 
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &hi)
    http.HandleFunc("/FileTest", FileTest)
    http.HandleFunc("/", MainPage)

    err := http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:" + strconv.Itoa(hi), nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err) 
        fmt.Print((hi))
    }
}
```

This starts a server that serves a main page and a download from an image. Both work very well and I get very good results from ab (Apache benchmark) up to 6 concurrent threads:

```
> ab -n 10000 -c 6 http://localhost:8080/
Concurrency Level:      6
Time taken for tests:   1.678096 seconds
Complete requests:      10000

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      1
  75%      1
  80%      1
  90%      2
  95%      2
  98%      2
  99%      2
 100%      3 (longest request)
```

When the concurrency level is set higher, this happens:

```
>ab -n 1000 -c 7 http://localhost:8080/
Concurrency Level:      7
Time taken for tests:   10.239586 seconds
Complete requests:      1000

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      2
  75%      2
  80%      3
  90%    499
  95%    505
  98%    507
  99%    507
 100%    510 (longest request)
```

Note that I only made 1'000 requests this time and it still took almost 6 times as much time.

Both benchmarks don't even request the file yet.

I don't know a lot about Go yet, but it seems that the Go runtime doesn't create enough OS threads to put the goroutines on, or something like that?

EDIT: I downloaded the new r60.2 from 07.10.2011.

Now it went even *worse*:

```
>ab -c 7 -n 1000 http://localhost:8080/
Concurrency Level:      7
Time taken for tests:   12.622722 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      1
  75%      2
  80%      2
  90%    496
  95%    503
  98%    506
  99%    506
 100%    507 (longest request)
```

Comment: I'm trying it out since it looks pretty awesome to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this benchmark with Go 64-bit at tip, and got the following results (on a Core 2 Duo 2GHz, Windows 7 x64):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin>ab -c 7 -n 1000 http://localhost:8080/
Concurrency Level:      7
Time taken for tests:   0.458 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      3
  66%      3
  75%      3
  80%      3
  90%      4
  95%      5
  98%      7
  99%      8
 100%      9 (longest request)
```

Comment: Go 64 bit? Where do I get those binaries from?

Comment: Do you care to share? I want them! I haven't been able to compile it in 64bit mode, not even with Mingw64...

Comment: Are you able to build the 386 version?  If so, and assuming you're using http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/mingw-w64-bin_i686-mingw_20110827.zip/download, just replace gcc.exe and ar.exe with the 64-bit versions, set GOARCH=amd64 and away you go.

Comment: I only replaced gcc.exe before, im trying with ar.exe now

Comment: I now compiled my test application using the 64 bit version and it runs BEAUTIFULLY. Thanks! I had to use "hg up weekly" though since the release didnt compile.

Answer (score 4):

As of today (Sep 2011) the Windows port of Go is a work-in-progress.  It lags behind the other supported platforms (Linux, etc.) in some important measures including stability and performance (though it is improving every day).  I would suggest that you try your test on a 64-bit Linux platform, and see how it differs, then maybe you can start deconstructing what's going wrong under Windows.

Comment: I have tested the exact same code on a virtual Linux system (the 6g 64-bit compiler here, on Windows only 8g is available, 32-bit) and even a concurrency of 1000 requests at the same time will not slow it down considerably (or even go faster). The times for 10.000 requests are all around 3.6 seconds which is rightfully so since it's a virtual system. So it seems the multi threading implementation on Windows just isn't up to the Linux implementation yet... I think. But it at least rules out implementational errors on my side... for now.